# How to develop Smart Client Application

Tags: c#, clickonce, smartclient

Hi.

I have several questions. I developed an application using Visual Studio 2010. The application is developed using Windows Form and the program was wrote using C#.

This application needs to be run on a server. There are several clients connected to the server that will access and use that application through the browser. I know this can be done using Smart Client technique. But I don't really understand how to do it. My questions are:

1. Is there any syntax/class/methods/function that I need to include in my application? How to use it?
2. What settings/configuration do I need to set up so that the client computer can access the application in the server through their browser?
3. I know this can be done using ClickOnce but I don't know how. Can anybody tell me or show me the steps that I need to do to implement this?

Comment: If your application is accessed through a browser, you do not need a ClickOnce deployment since there's no physical application on the user's machine except for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any syntax/class/methods/function that I need to include in my application? How to use it?

There are a few - but this is a large area. I would point you at couple:

- WCF
- ASP.NET Web API.

I would advise to use the later as it appears to be where the modern development is heading (at least to me).

Put simply, you will write your own web server, host it either in your WinForms application or migrate your WinForms to be a web application and host it on IIS, for example. Your web server will expose some API, which will likely to be based on HTTP protocol. A client application will hit web URLs. This will be a request-response paradigm.

Because this is a large area, I cannot name you exact classes, but have a look at [ASP.NET site](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for samples.

> What settings/configuration do I need to set up so that the client computer can access the application in the server through their browser?

It depends on the technology. Usually it's pretty simple - get it from tutorials and samples. In most cases this will be *.config file XML code and some minor bootstrapping in .cs files.

> I know this can be done using ClickOnce but I don't know how. Can anybody tell me or show me the steps that I need to do to implement this?

ClickOnce is a deployment tool. You probably don't need that at this point.